# Fill in the blank with preposition

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Adam adapted the drum ( ) the use in the concert

What will be used in the bracket?   I have already tried *to*, *from* and *for*.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That depends on what you want to say. Honestly, all three could fit with three different meanings. (Although if I were to use "for," I would remove "the.")

Comment: Was this on a test? I mean, is there no context for this question? It's just a stand-alone sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case *for* will be the correct preposition. The reason is following: the drum had not been changed by itself; it was rather modified by Adam in order to fit to the concert use. So I would choose the preposition 'for' and therefore would say:

> Adam adapted the drum **for** the use in the concert.

Comment: Hmm, the second 'the' needs to be omitted. 'Adam adapted the drum **for use** in the concert.' And I think 'to' would fit equally well there.

Answer (score -1):

Any of these prepositions would (just about) fit the sentence:

- before
- after
- for

I suspect there are more prepositions that would fit the sentence as well.

The sentence is a bit odd though with any of these - it would read better without *"the"*, for example:
*"Adam adapted the drum before use in the concert"*